# how to hide labels from Arcgisdynamic Layer javascriot/

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I want to hide labels from Arcgisdynamic layer.

Below is the code,

```
var drawingOptions = new LayerDrawingOptions();
drawingOptions.showLabels = false;
var options = [];
options[0] = drawingOptions;
mylayer.setLayerDrawingOptions(options);
var sls = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, esri.Color([255, 255, 0]), 3);
drawingOptions.renderer = SimpleRenderer(sls);
```

When i add the above code my layer is not showing. I am using javascript 3.0 API

Comment: It looks OK to me, I would suggest you to set the renderer before setting the options to the layer. The service supports dynamic layers?, you want to alter the first layer right?, it shows properly if you don't set the options?

Comment: Yes its show properly without setting the option but its show label

Comment: I don't know its my first layer. How can i know the layer index?

Comment: you can access the rest end point of the service, the one that ends `/MapServer/`, then find the layer you want to turn labels off, there you will see the number .. also when accessing the service check if the map service supports dynamic layers

Comment: Its first layer and i used renderer before set the option but still no display

Comment: The layer you are targeting is the only that is not displaying, or is the whole map?